# Android - Image upload to .net Web service Error

Tags: android, .net, web-services, android-asynctask, android-file

I have created the following code to connect to a .net Web Service API and upload a image. I am however presented with an error. Can someone please explain how this can be resolved?

```
 private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
 Button imageLoad, uploadBtn;
 ImageView imageView;
 TextView imagePath, message;
 String imgPath;
 private Bitmap bitmap;
 private ProgressDialog dialog;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    uploadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    imagePath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imagePath);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

    imageLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);               

        }
    });

    uploadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading 
      file...", true);
            new uploadFile().execute();
        }
    });
 }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Log.d("Selected image URI", selectedImage.toString());

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Log.d("Image Path Column", filePathColumn.toString());

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Log.d("Picture Path", picturePath);
        imagePath.setText(picturePath);
        imgPath = picturePath;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
 }


 class uploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        Log.d("b", b.toString());
        Log.d("baos", baos.toString());


        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "sendImage");        
        request.addProperty("myImage", b);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new   
     SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        envelope.dotNet = true; 
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        try {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending Pic", 
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "array length=" + b.length, 
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new 
                  HttpTransportSE("http://www.letstrend.com/spursService.asmx?WSDL");
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/sendImage", envelope);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            Log.d("Soap Response", result.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in catch e=" + e.getMessage(), 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fault=" + ((SoapFault) 
                  envelope.bodyIn).faultstring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return null;
    }

 }
```

The error showed in LogCat are

> ```
>     FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not 
>  called Looper.prepare()
> at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
> at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
> at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
> at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
> at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
> atcom.maan.fileuploadbinary.MainActivity$uploadFile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:150)
> atcom.maan.fileuploadbinary.MainActivity$uploadFile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
> ... 4 more
> ```

and

```
     Activity com.maan.fileuploadbinary.MainActivity has leaked  windowcom.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cd31e8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0- 456,144} that was originally android.view.WindowLeaked: 
     Activity com.maan.fileuploadbinary.MainActivity has leaked window    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40cd31e8 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
 at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
 at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
 at com.maan.fileuploadbinary.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:71)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong so that I can learn and correct my mistake.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not acces your UI-Thread from AsyncTask, your Toast tries to acces it. So please make all UI-Thread Actions in the onPostExecute and overgive this method something to work with, eg. an Object with your Bitmap and some string with a error.

```
//DEFINE TO RETURN A SOAP OBJECT
class uploadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SoapObject> {


//DEFINE TO RETURN A SOAP OBJECT
@Override
protected SoapObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

    Log.d("b", b.toString());
    Log.d("baos", baos.toString());


    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "sendImage");        
    request.addProperty("myImage", b);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new   
    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
    envelope.dotNet = true; 
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    try {
    // ---> THIS IS BAD!!!!
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending Pic", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "array length=" + b.length, 
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   //<------- DELETE IT

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new 
              HttpTransportSE("http://www.letstrend.com/spursService.asmx?WSDL");
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/sendImage", envelope);
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        Log.d("Soap Response", result.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  

// ---> THIS IS BAD!!!!      
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in catch e=" + e.getMessage(), 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fault=" + ((SoapFault) 
              envelope.bodyIn).faultstring, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//<------- DELETE IT

    }
    //TRY TO RETURN A MORE PROPRIATE OBJECT LIKE YOUR RESULT! AND HANDLE IT IN onPostExecute
    return result ;
}

@Override
onPostExecute(SoapObject result){

     if(result == null){
         Toast.makeText(_context, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         return;
     }
     //HANDLE YOUR RESULT HERE

}
```

Comment: Hi, A.S. Thanks for your reply. Can you please correct the coding and send me back. I don't understand what you said...

Comment: Made you a code, but please look out for a Android book, it has no sense to only copy it, becouse the next time you are going to use it you have no idea what to do!

Comment: Thank you so much A.S. I am just a newbee. I'll study the android book as you adviced...

Comment: sorry for the delay A.S.

Comment: @MKD I agree with A.S. Simply copying code is not going to be helpful to you for the future should you face similar problems again. Instead, learn and revise the code; understand what each code block is doing so that you can learn and create custom code;  and you will find that you can debug better since you will understand the code. Good luck